# MySQL Server 8.0 on a Windows machine, Prevent name resolution

Tags: mysql, configuration, configuration-files

My server is `MySQL Server 8.0` on a Windows machine.

I am getting the message:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'hostname.domain.co' (using password: YES)`

while I used an IP to connect to the database.

I would like to prevent the MySQL Server to perform name resolution.

I have seen the option `skip-name-resolve`.

I don't know if this would be a solution.

I tried to edit directly `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` (even if it is read-only).

But it didn't change anything.

```
shell> mysqld --verbose --help
```

shows:

```
skip-name-resolve    FALSE
```

Maybe this has to be set using `mysql_config_editor.exe`...

I also tried to add `--skip-name-resolve` in the `Start parameters` edit box in the `Services -> MYSLQ80 Properties` dialog box.

It didn't change anything.

Can you help me?

**EDIT 1**

```
mysql> show global variables like 'skip%';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| skip_external_locking | ON    |
| skip_name_resolve     | OFF   |
| skip_networking       | OFF   |
| skip_show_database    | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+

mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT 2**

I created the file `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini`
and put this into it:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve=ON
```

Now, if I run:

```
cmd.exe> mysqld --help --verbose
```

I can see that `skip-name-resolve` value has changed:

```
skip-name-resolve    TRUE
```

Yet, I am still getting an error while trying to connect to the server:

```
C:\> mysql -u root -h W.X.Y.Z -p
Enter password: ****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'hostname.domain.co' (using password: YES)
```

where `W.X.Y.Z` is this IP of the machine on which the MySQL server is running.

**EDIT 3**

I added a record in the `User` table of the `mysql` database:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM user WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND User='root';
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET Host = 'hostname.domain.co';
INSERT INTO user SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

This allows me to connect to the server as `mysql -u root -h W.X.Y.Z -p`

Comment: Does `show global variables like 'skip%';` show it? Are your grants in mysql.user IP or localhost based (`select user,host from mysql.user`)?

Comment: Hi. I edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: `mysql> SET skip_name_resolve = ON; ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'skip_name_resolve' is a read only variable`.
Can I force the grants to be IP-based?

Comment: It looks like you are doing the right things. Yes `skip_name_resolve` is read only. The grants are already hostbased. Work out how to get `skip-name-resolve` into the configuration file.

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone would tell me how to do that...

Comment: I edited my post (EDIT 3).